# How do I install wagtail 2.7?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, wagtail

How do I install `wagtail==2.7`? I already tried and I get this error

```
 The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


      [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> Pillow

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure. How do I handle this error?
```

Comment: it needs to compile some C/C++ code and it needs C/C++ headers file `*.h`  for C/C++ library `zlib`. On Linux it would need to install something like `libzlib-dev` or `zlib-dev` (`dev` means `develop` and it has files `*.h`)

Comment: maybe first try to install `pillow`. Did you check link in error message ? https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html There is suggestion to get precompliled `pillow` from page [PyPi](https://pypi.org) - see downloads for [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files)